# How can I delete the repeated data in MYSQL with over ten million data in it?

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-delete

I crawed lots of data, and saved it into mysql table, but there're some data duplicated, and I want to delete them in a effective way.

`table (ads_info)`

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ad_id            | varchar(64)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| adset_id         | varchar(64)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| campaign_id      | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| account_id       | varchar(64)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| conversion_specs | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| creative         | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| effective_status | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status           | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tracking_specs   | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| object_store_url | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| link             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| object_type      | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_time     | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_time     | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`show create table ads_info`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ads_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ad_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adset_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conversion_specs` text,
  `creative` text,
  `effective_status` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tracking_specs` text,
  `object_store_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `object_type` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ad_id` (`ad_id`),
  KEY `adset_id` (`adset_id`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18827534 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

There're over ten million ad info in the table, and about 40 thusand repeated. And I want delete all those repeated data.

Here's my poor trial

1）select all repeated ad_id

```sql
select ad_id  from ads_info group by ad_id having count(id) > 1;
#42387 rows in set (12.42 sec)
```

The query cost 12s, but I don't know how to do an optimization.

2) use subquery to delete all these repeated data.

```
delete  from ads_info where ad_id in ( select ad_id from (select ad_id from ads_info group by ad_id having count(id) > 1) t);
```

But I failed to get response from mysql with this trial, it seemed to be hanged with the query.

How can I delete these repeated data?

Comment: Both your queries delete ALL occurences of your duplicated data (e.g. if you have ad_id twice, you end up with 0 of those, not 1). Is that actually your intention?

Comment: @thanks for replying, yeah, I want delete them all, and do restoring work

Comment: It is almost certainly quicker to create a new table retaining just the info you wish to keep. Then DROP the old table. Then rename the new table (and add indexes, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed a `UNIQUE` key in the first place.  This will add it *and* dedup:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE ads_info
    ADD UNIQUE KEY(ad_id);
```

Comment: How about efficiency while there being ten million data total and  40 thusand repeated?

Comment: @jiaJimmy - Very inefficient _today_.  But the `UNIQUE` constraint prevents _future_ dups and the hassle of dealing with them.  BTW, use `INSERT IGNORE` if you want to silently ignore the dups in the future.

Comment: I'm using batch insert to  speed up save operation, and I don't know how to prevent dups in this situation.

Comment: I mean if  there is a `UNIQUE` ad_id, when I do `a 1000 batch insert`, and one of these 1000 is dup, then all these 1000 insert would fail. How to prevent this?

Comment: @jiaJimmy - No.  999 would be inserted, the one dup will be "ignored".  And an `id` will be "burned" because the 1000 auto_inc values are reserved first.  But that should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want delete all the occurence then

Instead of IN clause you could try using a join

```
  delete  ads_info 
  from ads_info 
  INNER JOIN  (
      select ad_id  
      from ads_info 
      group by ad_id 
      having count(*) > 1
  ) T ON T.ad_id = ads_info.ad_id
```

be sure you have and index  on ads_info.ad_id

if you have index  .. but the query optimizer don't use  and you are sure is a valid index  you could try using USE or FORCE

```
  delete  ads_info 
  from ads_info 
  INNER JOIN  (
      select ad_id  
      from ads_info 
      group by ad_id 
      having count(*) > 1
  ) T  FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (`ad_id`) ON T.ad_id = ads_info.ad_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've add an index on ad_id, but when I run command `delete from ads_info where ad_id =xxxxx`, I found the index not hitted, the delete command still cost lot of time..How can I make it more effective?

Comment: answer  updated ..   with a suggestion for index  use

Comment: your comment is not clear  to  me .. you have error also with the new sintax .?  .. show me the exact error message

Comment: Yeah, I've added into your comments above. I mean if I do a select join query like you provide it is correct, but delete command always failed

Comment: Sorry I'm not good at this and I'm hoping for your suggestion

Comment: .. answer  updated .. missing tablename  in delete clause

Comment: next time  .. instead of add the error messagge editing my answer   .. you should post the error message as comment or update  your question and add  the error message with proper enhancement